# How can we fix the UUID Mismatch issue, every time we content port certain Schemas from one env. to another?

Tags: web8.5, content-porter-2013, schema-synchronization

We are always facing an issue with mis-matched uuid, for few Schemas in our SDL Web 8.5 CMS.

For every deploy we have to manually update the Schema uuid to the value for the current environment. This needs to be done for every deploy.
Is it possible to fix this once and far all?
We should not face this issue while content port, the uuid should be environment specific.

Is there anything we are missing here?

Comment: Why would you need the uuid to be environment specific?

Comment: Actually, what I can understand is that, the schemas were created separately/manually in the 3 different environments, and that is why we're facing this issue. I just wanted to check if there is a way out for this issue, as we cannot get rid of the existing components if we want to sync all environments with content port of the schemas.

Answer (score 1):

In general, (XML) Schemas have a so-called Namespace URI which also affects the Components based on the Schema.

In Tridion, this Namespace URI is a property of a Schema. You cannot edit it directly, but it is obtained from the XSD. The default Namespace URI for newly created Schemas is a UUID (to ensure it is distinct from any other Schema).

The reason for this introduction: if you port a Schema between environments, its Namespace URI does **not** change. This is fortunately so, because changing the Namespace URI of a Schema on which Components are based has potentially huge impact; it effectively invalidates all existing Components based on the Schema.

I guess you are first manually creating the new Schema in both environments (effectively resulting in Schemas with different Namespace URIs) and later porting the Schema changes, resulting in the Namespace URI getting in sync between the environments (but a one time change on the target env.) ?

Comment: You can, of course, edit it in the source tab of the schema, if, for example, you'd prefer to have a human readable URI instead of a UUID. Of course, it makes sense to do this before you have any content that uses the schema.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that you're having a problem with these, as it's not normally a problem having different Schema UUIDs between environments.

As long as the Schema names and root element are the same, then you should be able to Content Port Components (and other Schemas) between environments without issue.

Do you just want to keep the UUIDs the same for cleanliness or are you experiencing a different problem if they're not consistent between environments?